# How to find a maximum value from a list of filenames in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

Ok, so I have a table that is extracting the value of a revision based on the file name found in the field Name. We have solidworks drawings `.SLDDRW` files, and `PDF`'s as well. For every `.SLDDRW` file, I have multiple `PDF` files that store each revision level, and I'm trying to find the maximum revision, and then set a field on the `SLDDRW` based on what's found in the PDF File name, since the `SLDDRW` files never had the metadata input for the revision.

So I would have something like this:

```
Name
---------------
file1 Rev A.PDF
file1 Rev B.PDF
file1 Rev C.PDF
file1 Rev D.PDF
file1.SLDDRW
```

So the maximum value for rev's in the filename is Rev D, so I need to extract that and assign it to the `SLDDRW` in the revision field.

With this code, I've gotten pretty close:

```
UPDATE       Drawings 
SET                Drawings.CurrentStateName = PDFs.CurrentStateName
FROM            Files AS Drawings 
                INNER JOIN 
                Files AS PDFs ON 
                         REVERSE(
                             SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Drawings.Name), CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(Drawings.Name)) + 1, 999)) = 
                             SUBSTRING(PDFs.NAME,0,CHARINDEX('REV', PDFs.name)) 
WHERE 
    Drawings.Name LIKE '%.slddrw' 
    AND PDFs.CurrentStateName IS NOT NULL 
    AND Drawings.FolderID = PDFs.FolderID
```

But it only works SOMETIMES. Some times it'll be the maximum value, sometimes it'll be the minimum. How can I force it to be the maximum value found?

When I do this, I'm able to get the maximum value for a file:

```
DECLARE @MaxRevValue VARCHAR(2);

SELECT @MaxRevValue = MAX(PDFs.CurrentStateName) 
    FROM Files AS Drawings 
                INNER JOIN 
                Files AS PDFs ON REVERSE(
                             SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Drawings.Name), CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(Drawings.Name)) + 1, 999)) = 
                             SUBSTRING(pdfS.NAME,0,CHARINDEX('REV', pdfS.name))
            WHERE 
    Drawings.Name LIKE '%.slddrw' 
    AND PDFs.CurrentStateName IS NOT NULL 
    AND Drawings.FolderID = PDFs.FolderID
    -- AND Drawings.Name Like '<filename to spot check>'
```

but it sets `@MaxValue` to the absolute maximum value found, not the one relative to the individual file it's looking at.... so I'm stumped at this point.

I tried putting the value found in like this just below it running the same query twice but inputting the found `@MaxRevValue` found, but it's not doing it the way I hoped. Then I tried nesting one join into the other, but I couldn't get that to work either.

```
--SELECT distinct CurrentStateName from ImportFiles order by CurrentStateName
DECLARE @MaxRevValue VARCHAR(2);

SELECT @MaxRevValue = MAX(PDFs.CurrentStateName) 
    FROM Files AS Drawings 
                INNER JOIN 
                Files AS PDFs ON REVERSE(
                             SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Drawings.Name), CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(Drawings.Name)) + 1, 999)) = 
                             SUBSTRING(pdfS.NAME,0,CHARINDEX('REV', pdfS.name))
            WHERE 
    Drawings.Name LIKE '%.slddrw' 
    AND PDFs.CurrentStateName IS NOT NULL 
    AND Drawings.FolderID = PDFs.FolderID
    AND Drawings.Name LIKE '<filename to spot check>'

--copy revision value from the PDF to the drawing with the same root name
UPDATE       Drawings 
SET                Drawings.CurrentStateName = @MaxRevValue
FROM            Files AS Drawings 
                INNER JOIN 
                Files AS PDFs ON 
                         REVERSE(
                             SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Drawings.Name), CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(Drawings.Name)) + 1, 999)) = 
                             SUBSTRING(pdfS.NAME,0,CHARINDEX('REV', pdfS.name)) 
WHERE 
    Drawings.Name LIKE '%.slddrw' 
    AND PDFs.CurrentStateName IS NOT NULL 
    AND Drawings.FolderID = PDFs.FolderID
```

Any pointers?

`CurrentStateName` is just a placeholder I'm using for the revision value found. I'm parsing that using other code, but I've got it to where it's accurately finding the value.

Comment: I would recommend checking out using MAX() as a [Window function](https://www.sqlshack.com/use-window-functions-sql-server/) to get the maximum revision per file. What database are you using?

Comment: @Isaac This is MSSQL. 

Window function? I don't know what that is, I'll have to look that up.

Comment: Window functions are going to blow your mind. The have been around for quite some time (introduced in 2005, enhanced in 2012). I just started using them in the last 3 years. Here is another [resource](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/introduction-to-t-sql-window-functions/).

Comment: @Isaac so this worked, I was able to get the max value, but I can't assign it to the SLDDRW, I haven't managed to figure that out

Comment: I may have gotten you off track  stating you should use MAX() as a window function. A window function will definitely work here, but ROW_NUMBER() is the function you want.

Answer (score 0):

It is always helpful to provide sample data to work with. In the absence of that, I have created my own along with some assumptions that may be incorrect. However, I think this will get you close.

With some string manipulation I pulled out the first part of the file name which am calling **FolderID** and the **Revision**. Then using **ROW_NUMBER()** as a window function I get the maximum Revision for each FolderID and use that as the basis for my update statement.

```
UPDATE Files
SET    CurrentStateName = MaxRevision.Revision
FROM   
(
    SELECT PDFs.*
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PDFs.FolderID 
          ORDER BY Revision DESC) AS [RowNumber]
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT *
            , LEFT(Name, CHARINDEX(' ', Name) - 1)                          AS [FolderID]
            , SUBSTRING(Name, LEN(Name) - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(Name)), 1) AS [Revision]
        FROM  Files
        WHERE Name LIKE '%.PDF'
    ) AS PDFs
) AS MaxRevision
WHERE  MaxRevision.RowNumber = 1
   AND Files.Name LIKE '%SLDDRW'
   AND Files.Name LIKE MaxRevision.FolderID + '%';
```

He is the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a67df2256b6af2db4b6755b6608dddcc) with sample data to see it in action. One assumption is the **Revision** will always be just one character.

I hope this gets you going on the right path.